# Sending JSON from PHP to JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm asking my server for some data. I used an AJAX call with a JSON object (which contains the ID of the selected object), and I want the server to return back to the AJAX call a new JSON object containing all the information about the product with the specified ID. here below there's the code

**JavaScript**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // AJAX request on submit (login form)
    $("#form-login").submit(function (e) { // this works
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "submit.php",
            data: {
                Email: document.getElementById('login-email').value, // Email in the form
                Password: document.getElementById('login-password').value // Password in the form
        },
            cache: false,
            success: function() {
                window.location.href = "home.php"; // load the home.php page in the default folder
            }
        });
    });

    function getProduct(ID_product) {
        //AJAX request to get a product data from the server
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "product.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                 id_product: ID_product // the id of the single product
            },
            // success: function(data){ // here begin problems
            //     var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            //     alert(obj); // debug
            // }
            complete: alert("TEST")
        });
    }
});
```

**PHP, product.php** code:

```
<?php
require('include/header.php');

#Detect AJAX and POST request, if is empty exit
if((empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') or empty($_POST)){
    exit("Empty post to product.php");
}

if(!empty($_POST)){
    $id = $_POST['id_product'];

    $query_findProduct =  $db->query("SELECT Name, Description, Price, Available FROM PRODUCTS WHERE ID_product='$id' ");
    $product = $query_findProduct->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    output($product);
}
?>
```

**PHP, output function:**

```
# Function to set JSON output
function output($Return=array()){
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    #exit(json_encode($Return)); # what's the difference with echo?
    echo json_encode($Return); # what's the difference with exit?
}
```

**Home.php** code for utility:

```
<?php
# getting all the product
$query_showProducts =  $db->query("SELECT ID_product, Name, Description, Picture, Price FROM PRODUCTS");

# putting all the products in an array
$products = array(); # an array that will contain all the product in the DB
while($prod = $query_showProducts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $products[] = $prod; # filling the array
}

#query that will store the total number of products in $productNumTot
$query_countProducts =  $db->query("SELECT COUNT(ID_product) FROM PRODUCTS");
$transitory = $query_countProducts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$productNumTot = $transitory['COUNT(ID_product)']; # total number of products

?>

<div id="products_area">
    <div id="categories">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Other</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Laptop</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Smartphone</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="products">

        <?php
        for ($i=0; $i<$productNumTot; $i++){
            ?>
                <div id="product-box" onclick="getProduct(<?= $products[$i]['ID_product'] ?>)">
                    <div id="product-area-image">
                        <div id="product-image">
                            <?php
                                echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode( $products[$i]['Picture'] ).'"/>';
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="product-name">
                        <p><?= $products[$i]['Name'] ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="product-price">
                        <p><?= $products[$i]['Price'] ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php
        }
        ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

My question is: will the server store the JSON object in a global variable for sending it back to the AJAX request? How can the client be able to receive and display the JSON obtained from the server (have I to build a function in JS with a parameter that will contain the JSON response?)? What I have to do if I simply want my client to pick this JSON and display it?

I apologize for the question, but I'm desperate!

Comment: actually what you're doing seems right - from a quick look  if you uncomment the success-callback. You've commented _`// here begin problems`_ - what problems?

Comment: The problem is that my server recive the request, and it do the echo of the product, but then on the client side I don't recive nothing! As you said, my code seems right. I don't know where is my error...

Answer (score 2):

in your js file:

```
 function getProduct(ID_product) {
        //AJAX request to get a product data from the server
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "product.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                 id_product: ID_product // the id of the single product
            },
            success: function(data){ // data is a json object
                  console.log(data);//don't convert it (it's already an object)
            }
        });
```